# what Python libraries exist to work with jsonml? ideally , it will be a format converter .xml, .json, .html

Tags: jsonml

what Python libraries exist to work with jsonml? ideally , it will be a format converter .xml, .json, .html

I haven't found any libraries yet. Is it possible to create such a library or write the appropriate code.
found a few for java but not for python